# Floor summing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, sum, discrete-mathematics

Is there a fast algorithm that could compute

[image: formula]

? p, q, k, l, A and B are integers. By "fast" I mean that it should be much faster than a simple O(B-A) loop.

Related:
If we set k = 0, there is an O(log(p) + log(q)) algorithm that solves the problem.

Comment: So although `p` and `q` are integers, you don't want integer division? If the factors `p/q` and `k/l` are constants, there's little sense in using them in your big-O notation.

Comment: the complexity you are asking for does not make sense: you are adding N elements N=B-A; p,q,k,l do not influence the number of steps taken to compute the final sum, hence the do not influence the complexity. Maybe what you want is something better than O(n) which is what the formula gives you.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev: there is a floor function that prevents you from doing that

Comment: @M Oehm, Pandrel: O(B-A) must be avoided. The complexity comes from a related algorithm that solves the problem when k=0 -- that one has complexity O(log(p) + log(q)).

Comment: I edited the problem statement as it confused a lot of people.

Comment: Are your numbers large enough that you're using arbitrary precision arithmetic? If so, you should really mention that.

Comment: @JayKominek: Not necessarily. To be concrete, let's say all the nubmers are <= 10^12.

Comment: Mmmm there's probably some dynamic programming solution logging previously calculated values of the function for some value of x and then calculating new values in terms of the previously calculated ones. I don't think the floor would bottleneck the complexity--It's just two distinct integer divisions, one on p/q and one on k/l, correct?

If you elaborate the O(log(p) + log(q)) solution for the k=0 case, the answer to your question may become immediately evident.

Comment: If I got your DP solution correctly, you would need to find how do remainders modulo q.l cycle around, but such a solution would be too slow, namely omega(q.l). The solution for k=0 is relies on an algorithm similar to Euclid's algorithm: if p>=q, reduce so that p<q. Otherwise, transpose the system so that again p > q and deduce the solution from that number.

Comment: @Zuza I think I've got a formula for p = 1 with O(1+n%q)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in time O(q). (I assume p and q are relatively prime otherwise you should just reduce the fraction first).

For each integer r in the range [A, A+q) you can determine the value of

```
floor [p*(A+r)/q + k/l]
```

Let it be n(r). Then you can re-express your sum as

```
sum_{r=0}^{q} sum_{y=0}^{y_max(r)} (n(r)+p*y),
```

where

```
y_max(r) = floor[ (B-A)/q ]
```

Now each inner sum can be computed in O(1) as it is fully explicit, and you get O(q) in total.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm still looking for something that can work with values like 10^12.

Comment: p, q, k, l, A, B or any combination of them :)